# Почему xdebug показывает один файл index?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

Всем привет, второй день капаюсь с проблемой подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело?

Настроил Xdebug все ок

```html
[xdebug]
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_enable = true
xdebug.remote_host = 10.0.75.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

прослушивание работает. Проект на Laravel

Но почему то отладка не идет должным образом по тем файлам по которым должен выполняться скрипт. Работает только по файлу index.php. То есть я ожидаю что когда отправляю Post запрос как в данном случае у меня xdebug должен показывать ход выполнения скрипта пошагово. Открылся один файл в нем отработалась нужная функция, при нажатии на след шаг f7 открылся другой файл с другой функцией и тд. Но у меня почему то кроме index.php больше ничего не отображается...

короткий видео пример с проблемой

[Смотреть видео с проблемой 1](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/DCkQ%2F6ESXcHwsR)

[Смотреть видео с проблемой 2](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/8SN8%2Fuj9XXRhcw)

Вот тут видел как у парня на ларавеле все ок работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня xdebug так же начается с файла index но потом переходит в следующий, где стоит Breakpoint.
А вы Breakpoint ставите (красную точку для отслеживания) в контроллере?